# "Pack" a np.array of 4 np.uint16 into a single np.unit64

Tags: python, numpy, unsigned-integer

Given a `np.array` of 4 `np.uint16`

```
input = np.random.randint(10, size=4, dtype=np.uint16)
```

how can I "pack" their binary representations into a single `np.uint64`?

```
# Example of C code
# output = input[0] | input[1] << 16 | input[2] << 32 | input[3] << 48
```

The order in which the 4 `np.uint16` are packed is not important (provided it's not random).

Comment: Would `281483566710792` be your expected output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can *reinterpret* bytes of an array with `np.view`:

```py
input.view(np.uint64) # 844429225558024 on my x86-64 machine
```

This does not perform any copy or computation. It is performed quickly and in a constant-time. However, the order of the bytes is **architecture-dependent** due to the **endianness**. It is little-endian on most architectures, including x86-64, most ARM processors and recent POWER processors.

Note that `input.view(np.uint64).view(np.uint16)` is guaranteed to give you the input array here.

Note that regarding the wanted endianness, you can [swap the bytes](https://numpy.org/devdocs/user/basics.byteswapping.html) of Numpy arrays.

Comment: Thanks! This looks like exactly what I wanted. Regarding the order, I don't mind as long as it's consistent on a given machine.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution:

```
output = np.bitwise_or.reduce(input << (np.arange(len(input)) * 16))
```

Output:

```
>>> output
281483566710792
```

(Side-note: don't use names of Python builtins (e.g. `input`) as a variable names. :)